# How to serve SPA with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

This isn't a question but an answer :D

Problem: I need to return the page `index.html` if the route did not match

```
//.. routing and etc.

var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "YourSpaStaticFileDirectory"));

// serve static files of spa
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider
});

// return index.html if no route matched
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider
});
```

I created this question because I couldn't find a working answer. As a result, after digging into the documentation, I tried `MapFallbackToFile` with `StaticFileOptions` and everything worked

Comment: Just in case. This is an answer not a question

Comment: Since you posted it as a question, it has to be a question, it cannot be an answer, because you would have to post an answer as an answer.